# Constructing a sequence of k-wise independent random variables, with non trivial tail sigma algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

I am trying to construct a sequence of random variables $ \left(X_{i}\right)_{i=1}^{\infty} $ which are k-wise independent, but with non trivial $\sigma$ algebra. This will show that the independence in Kolmogorov 0-1 rule is indeed required.

I know that for a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ we can construct $ \left|\mathbb{F}\right| $ random variables which are k-wise independent, using polynomials of degree $k-1$, but as I tried to mimic this behavior for infinite fields (such as $\mathbb{Q}$) I got into trouble. And I am also not really sure how to analyze their tail $\sigma$ algebra.

I tried to construct such sequence using random graphs, or using perculations, but failed.